# Powershell FTP won't list files on server

Tags: powershell, ftp

I want to make a backup script for ZyWall USG 20.
I used this Powershell code to get a list of the content in the directory:

```
[System.Net.FtpWebRequest]$ftp = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("ftp://*server*/*path*")
$ftp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("*user*","*password*") 
$ftp.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+FTP]::ListDirectory
$response = $ftp.getresponse()
echo $response
```

I expected to get a list of all the files..
instead I get this:

```
PS Z:\> ...\list-files-test.ps1


ContentLength           : -1
Headers                 : {}
SupportsHeaders         : True
ResponseUri             : ftp://*server*/*path*/
StatusCode              : OpeningData
StatusDescription       : 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for file list

LastModified            : 01.01.0001 00:00:00
BannerMessage           : 220 FTP Server (ZyWALL USG 20) [::ffff:*server*]

WelcomeMessage          : 230 User *user* logged in

ExitMessage             : 
IsFromCache             : False
IsMutuallyAuthenticated : False
ContentType             : 




PS Z:\>
```

Why don' I get a list of files?
I checked it with filezilla - the folder is not empty.
And I can download specific files using `[System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::DownloadFile`.

Comment: Also it takes like  a crazy amount of time to execute the script

Comment: You are not done yet. You need to read and parse the response stream ($response.GetResponseStream())

Comment: Thank you - I don't know why I forgot that ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WebRequest.GetResponse()` makes the remote call and gets the response details, but there's no *content* within the [response](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) itself.

Instead, you need to continue on and read the response stream out of the response with [`WebResponse.GetResponseStream()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e9ed26c9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).